# Remove all named ranges assigned to different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "Save Inputs" macro in a tool I created which copies the main input sheet in order to save the values for later. The macro removes comments and other unnecessary parts of the original sheet. The tool itself has a bunch of range names, and these get copied along with the sheet. I am trying to delete all of them from the saved input sheet, but encountering an error.

```
Sub SaveProgramData()

Dim SheetCopy As Worksheet
Dim BookCopy As Workbook
Dim nm As Name
Set Analyzer = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Program Dashboard")
Analyzer.copy

Set SheetCopy = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'only way to address copy of a sheet created in new wkbk (i think)
Set BookCopy = SheetCopy.Parent

With SheetCopy
'remove comments, buttons, data validation, do some formatting, etc.
End With


For Each nm In BookCopy.Names
    nm.Delete 'this results in a runtime error saying the name I entered is not valid
Next


End Sub
```

I'm confused because I'm not trying to enter a name, just delete them. I'm also open to another method of copying the sheet that won't keep the names.

EDIT: See comment below, the problem is that most of the names were assigned to ranges in the original workbook. Solved by adding additional condition to `If` statement:

```
For Each nm In BookCopy.Names
      If InStr(1, nm.RefersTo, SheetCopy.Name) > 1 Or InStr(1, nm.RefersTo, ThisWorkbook.Name) > 1 Then 'check for names scoped to copied sheet, or original workbook
         nm.Delete
      End If
Next nm
```

Comment: First, you should add the `.` before `Range("B6")`. Second, what error specifically are you getting? Perhaps do `For each nm in ThisWorkbook.Names`?

Comment: Erorr message is "The name you entered is not valid. Reasons for this can include..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize the `Names` variable, so it doesn't know what to loop through.

Try this instead:

Create the following Sub:

```
Sub RemoveNamesFromSheet()

Dim nm As Name

   For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
      If InStr(1, nm.RefersTo, ActiveSheet.Name) > 1 Then
         nm.Delete
      End If
   Next nm

End Sub
```

Then simply replace your loop with `RemoveNamesFromSheet`

Hope that does the trick!

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. No error message but all the names are still there. I actually had `Names` intialized in an earlier version but it didn't work, so I tried it the way I posted.

Comment: Upon further inspection, this did work - but most of the names are actually still assigned the original workbook, and it only removed ones that were scoped to the copied sheet. Any way to remove those other names, while leaving the ones in the original tool intact?

Comment: OK, I solved it. I had to pay better attention to the `If` statement in John's code - it deletes any name that has the active sheet in its reference. I added a second condition and an `Or` operator to check for names that have `ThisWorkbook` (the original workbook, where the code is running) in its `RefersTo` and this got rid of all the names. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your last `for` loop should be  `for nm in BookCopy.Names`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this:

```
Sub RemoveNamesFromSheet()
  Dim nm As Name
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
  For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(nm, "C:\") > 1 Then
      nm.Delete
    End If
  Next nm
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Calculate
End Sub
```

It checks the name for the occurrence of "C:\" which is normally the name of another workbook, so all external references are removed. It assumes the workbooks referring to are closed.
You may also replace "C:\" with the filename that you just copied from. Temporarily disabling automatic recalculation speeds up the process dramatically.